# retrieve table and column names in SQR file

Tags: sqr

I have a SQR file that was previously used by my colleague to pull a database. Now he left and we need to take the pull and modify it, then integrate it into a new SQL pulling process. But the SQR file is binary and not viewable.

The question is: how should we retrieve the table and column names from the binary SQR file?

Thank you!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the SQL is stored as plain text inside the SQT. You would just need to open the SQT with your favorite text editor and search for SELECT. It will take a bit of effort to parse out all the text, but you can do it; at least with version 9, which we use. But this is a rather odd approach, why not just look at the database to get the fields you need?

Comment: @Bob, thank you for the comment!  Sorry I have no idea about SQT. Is it a software?

Comment: When you "compile" an SQR, you end up with an SQT, so when you said a binary SQR I thought you were talking about an SQT. I've never heard of a binary SQR, sorry.

Comment: Are you able to open your file with something like Notepad++?